# Question regarding Symmetric group and induction

Tags: group-theory, induction, proof-explanation, permutation-cycles

I have no clue what to do here !

> Let $n>1$ be a natural number. the m-cycle
>   $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_m)$ denotes a permutation in $S_n$ where
>   $\sigma(a_1)=a_2,\sigma(a_2)=a_3,\dots, \text{ and }\sigma(a_m)=a_1$.
>
> Prove by induction on $k \geq 1$ that if $k+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$, then $\sigma^k(a_i)=a_j$
>   whenever $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq m$.

**Pained Attempt :**

Let $n>1$ be a natural number. the m-cycle $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_m)$ denotes a permutation in $S_n$ where
$\sigma(a_1)=a_2,\sigma(a_2)=a_3,\dots, \text{ and }\sigma(a_m)=a_1$.

[Base Step]

For the base case,$k=1$, assume that $1+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$ and prove that $\sigma^1(a_i)=a_j$ whenever $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq m$.

With $1+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$ then $i\equiv j-1 (mod\text{ m})$ iff $m|i-j+1$ or equivalently $i=mg+j-1$ for some $g \in \Bbb{Z}$. Therefore $\sigma^1(a_i)=\sigma(a_{mg+j-1}).....?$

Is this approach even right??
Thank you for your help

Comment: Note that $1\le i,j\le m$, so there are only 2 cases:$i=j-1$ or $j=1,i=m$. The induction part is similar.

Comment: Maybe this will help with the base case, you're trying to show that $k = 1$ (*one application of $\sigma$*) will take you from $a_i \to a_j$, where $j$ is just $i+k \mod{m}$.Well indeed this is true, if $i < m$, then $\sigma(a_i) = a_{i+1}$ and we win. Otherwise if $i = m$, then $\sigma(a_i) = a_1$, which is $k+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

Comment: Thank you TrostAft,I am very confused...i think i understand how you got $j \equiv i+k (\mod m)$ is the following right :  $k+i \equiv j (\mod m)$ imples that $m | k+i-j$ implies $ j-k-i = mh$ for some $h \in \Bbb{Z}$ and hence $m | j-(k+i) $ and finally $j \equiv i+k (\mod m)$...then you made a distinction between two cases [1] i<m and [2] i=m...For i<m, and k=1 given that we are in the base step, then $j=mh+i+k = mh+i+1$...am i right in assuming that if we can show that $j=mh+i+1=i+1$, then we can show that $\sigma(a_i)=a_{i+1}=a_j$???...i am confused!