# Proof by induction involving symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I am aware that i have posted this question before, but the comments i received did not really help silly old me. So i would appreciate it if someone can walk me through some parts of the problem. I have revised my attempt from the previous post, accounting for the comments i have received as i understood them.

> Let $n>1$ be a natural number. the m-cycle
>   $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_m)$ denotes a permutation in $S_n$ where
>   $\sigma(a_1)=a_2,\sigma(a_2)=a_3,\dots, \text{ and }\sigma(a_m)=a_1$.
>
> Prove by induction on $k \geq 1$ that if $k+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$, then $\sigma^k(a_i)=a_j$
>   whenever $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq m$.

**Pained Attempt :**

Let $n>1$ be a natural number. the m-cycle $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_m)$ denotes a permutation in $S_n$ where
$\sigma(a_1)=a_2,\sigma(a_2)=a_3,\dots, \text{ and }\sigma(a_m)=a_1$.

[Base Step]

For the base case,$k=1$, assume that $1+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$ and prove that $\sigma^1(a_i)=a_j$ whenever $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq m$.

Since $1+i\equiv j (mod\text{ m})$ then $j \equiv 1+i (mod\text{ m})$ and $m | j-(1+i)$ hence $j = mh+i+1$ for some $h \in \Bbb{Z}$.

**[case:$1 \leq i \lt m$]**

Since $j=mh+i+1$ then $a_j=a_{mh+i+1}$. By assumption $\sigma(a_{mh+i})=a_{mh+i+1}=a_j$.

I am not sure how to proceed further here..

I thought:
With $1 \leq i \lt m$ and mh+i+1 being constrained to lie between 1 and m given the definition of the m-cycle, this implies that h must be 0 (?).Therefore $\sigma(a_{m(0)+i})=a_{m(0)+i+1}=a_j$ and $\sigma(a_{i})=a_{i+1}=a_j$ as required (?)

...this feels iffy.

**[case: $i=m$]**

Since $j=mh+i+1$ then $a_j=a_{mh+m+1}$ and $a_j=a_{m(h+1)+1}$ . By assumption $\sigma(a_{m(h+1)})=a_{m(h+1)+1}=a_j$.

I am not sure how to proceed further either..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When reposting a question, you should link to the [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210074/question-regarding-symmetric-group-and-induction). It's also good to be as specific as possible about what you didn't understand about the given responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting hung up on completely irrelevant details. Once you know $k$ and $i$, you know $j$. There's no need to delve into modular arithmetic and introduce new variables. Here's a complete proof of the base step:

**Base case:**

Let $k=1$ and let $1\leq i,j\leq m$ be such that $k+i\equiv j\pmod{m}$. We distinguish two cases:

1. If $1\leq i<m$ then $1<k+i\leq m$ and so $j=k+i=1+i$. Then $\sigma^1(a_i)=\sigma(a_i)=a_{i+1}=a_j$.
2. If $i=m$ then $k+i=m+1$ and so $j=1$. Then $\sigma^1(a_i)=\sigma(a_m)=a_1=a_j$.

Can you now prove the induction step?

Comment: Thank you for the response Servaes,does the modulo not matter at all here?? Also how did you get j=1 in (2.) please? Thanks again.

Comment: You are given as the definition of $\sigma$ that $\sigma(a_m)(=\sigma^1(a_m))=a_1$.  That step is where the modulo comes in.

Comment: somehow..i do not understand how j=1 in (2.) above,could someone explain please?

Comment: Regarding (2.) : $i=m \Rightarrow i+k=m+k \Rightarrow i+1=m+1$. Since $k+i \equiv j (\mod m)$ then $1+m \equiv j (\mod m) \Rightarrow m | (1+m)-j \Rightarrow j-1=m(1-h) \Rightarrow m | (j-1) \Rightarrow m \leq (j-1) \Rightarrow j \geq m+1$. But $1 \leq j \leq m \lt m+1$...which contradicts $j \leq m+1$ ??...it seems simple but..i am twisiting my self into pretzels!

Comment: Sorry! i was editing :)

Comment: @HalfAFoot Since $k=1$ and $i=m$, it is *immediate* from the definition that
$$1+m\equiv j\pmod{m}.$$
Everything you wrote before that is completely irrelevant. Further, the implication
$$m\mid(j-1)\quad\implies\quad m\leq(j-1),$$
is false. Instead simply note that
$$1+m\equiv 1\pmod{m}\qquad\text{ so }\qquad j\equiv1\pmod{m}.$$
Because $1\leq j\leq m$ it follows that $j=1$. Do not focus on the modular arithmetic, it is just a formality here.

Comment: Goodness gracious,thank you Servaes.

Comment: @Servaes,given $1+m\equiv j\pmod{m}$ are we 'artifically choosing' j=1 to yield: $1+m\equiv 1\pmod{m}\qquad\text{ so }\qquad j\equiv1\pmod{m}$....?..what if we had chosen j not 1??  the reason i was using arithmetic was to have j 'drop out' as 1. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'artificially choosing'? For any value of $x$ the congruence
$$j\equiv x\pmod{m},$$
has a *unique* solution $j$ with $1\leq j\leq m$. For $x=1$ this is clearly $j=1$.

Comment: So..the 1 on the RHS of $1+m\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ is not a j chosen as 1 for $1+m\equiv j\pmod{m}$?

Comment: I do not understand your question. It should be more than obvious that $1+m\equiv1\pmod{m}$ by definition.

Comment: @Servaes, you are ofcourse right..! Thank you very much for walking me through this :) ...i did not realise your point about there being a unique solution j with 1<=j<=m..after flipping through my book the closest result i have found is : For each integer a there is exactly one integer r in the list 0,...,m-1 s.t. a is congruent to r (modulo m) or more precisely : 0<=r<m...Thanks again

Comment: @HalfAFoot That is precisely the result you need; of course $m\equiv0\pmod{m}$ so in stead of the list $0,\ldots,m-1$ you can take the list $1,\ldots,m$.